# Mongoose Schema.index on multiple fields does not work with tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose, mocha.js, chai-as-promised

I have created an `uploadSchema` (`mongoose.Schema`) with the fields (among the rest): key and bucket. each of them alone is not unique but together I want them to create a unique id.
in my code, I used the line (right after declaring the `uploadSchema` and right before the `uploadModel`):

```
uploadSchema.index({ key: 1, bucket: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true });
```

but then, in my tests (`mocha` and `chai`), the indexing is not enforced, and so I can create two instances with the same key and bucket (in my case). 
for example, in my code:

```
await uploadModel.create({ key: testUpload.key, bucket: testUpload.bucket, 
name: 'name1',  ownerID: USER.id, parent: null }).should.eventually.exist;
```

and right after that:

```
await uploadModel.create({key: testUpload.key, bucket: testUpload.bucket,
 name: 'name1', ownerID: USER.id, parent: null }).should.eventually.be.rejected;
```

does not throw the right error error:

```
AssertionError: expected promise to be rejected but it was fulfilled with { Object ($__, isNew, ...) }
```

Am I not using it correctly? Or is there a problem with indexing and testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I figured it out!
Apparently, I used `mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();`  in my afterEach of the tests. That means that the indexes were reset each time. 
So what I did was to recreate the indexes each time in my tests:

```
  before(async () => {
    // Remove files from DB
    const collections = ['files', 'uploads'];
    for (const i in collections) {
      mongoose.connection.db.createCollection(collections[i], (err) => {});
    }
    await mongoose.connection.collections['files'].createIndex({ name: 1, parent: 1, ownerID: 1 }, { unique: true });
    await mongoose.connection.collections['uploads'].createIndex({ key: 1, bucket: 1 }, { unique: true });
  });
```

And in the beforeEach:

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const removeCollectionPromises = [];
    for (const i in mongoose.connection.collections) {
      removeCollectionPromises.push(mongoose.connection.collections[i].deleteMany({}));
    }
    await Promise.all(removeCollectionPromises);
  });
```

afterEach is empty.
now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you set `autoIndex` to false in your connection (which is recommended to do).

Either add it to you Schema:

`let uploadSchema =  mongoose.Schema({ ... }, {autoIndex: true});`

But i would recommend just building the index yourself on the database, i think its the safest way around it.

Comment: autoIndex doesn't fix it, and I don't want to do it manually because we have automatic tests with jenkins so it won't pass

Comment: can you share what index's are already built in that database?